# Insert wp_query after the_content with plugin (filter the_content won't work)

Tags: wp-query, filters, the-content

I would like to insert a wp_query after the post content. After looking in different website, they all suggest using a filter on the_content. Example:
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop' );

```
function add_query_after_content( $content ) {

        echo $content;
        echo *** The query ****;
    }

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_query_after_content' )
```

However it creates an infinite loop (the content in the query is filtered as well).

What is a good way to entering the query automatically after the post, **using a plugin that will work on most themes** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove your hook before query.

```
function wpse_288691_add_query_after_content( $content ) {

    $ouptut = '';

    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_288691_add_query_after_content' );

    // Do your *** WP_Query ***  and assign result to $ouptut.
    // Reset query by executing `wp_reset_query`.

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_288691_add_query_after_content' );

    return $content . $ouptut;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_288691_add_query_after_content' );
```

Do not `echo` anything inside the filter, only return values.

Comment: it was not the add/remove filter that solve my problem, but using return insteat of echo